# What is the term for the light-sensitive metals in the photoelectric effect?

Tags: terminology, photoelectric-effect, metals

Can anyone please tell me the term used to refer to metals such as those used in [photoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) which can generate a current from light?

Comment: Are you hoping for a specific term which was designed for the context of the photoelectric effect, or are you trying to find out which general category of metals displays the photoelectric effect (i.e. we usually say it's best observed in alkali metals like potassium and cesium)

Comment: The former (a specific term which was designed for the context of the photoelectric effect).  I once came across this term but cannot recall waht it was.  Maybe photo-something?  I can't remember.

Comment: Did you take a look at the proposed answer? :)

Comment: Sorry it wasn't that. I will see if I can find it amongst my old material and will post the answer here after the weekend (if I find it).

Answer (score 1):

"Low-work-function materials"

"Photoemitting materials"

"Photocathode materials"

(ah, old question bumped by Community)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for photosensitive.

Answer (score 0):

All materials will exhibit a photoelectric effect, but when one makes
an assembly (a phototube) for that purpose, the light-sensing metal surface is
called the cathode (or photocathode) of the phototube.

A cathode may also be an electrode in water that is electrically biased so
that it loses electrons into the surrounding medium, or a battery terminal
in a dry cell.   But, it is always the negative terminal, the electron
emitting component, of any of these.

Answer (score 0):

The terms you're looking for could be

- photoelectrode
- photovoltaic metal
- photoconductive metal